# ubuntu автозапуск сервера

Tags: ubuntu, автозапуск

Есть заказчик к которому я подключаюсь удаленно по java iKVM Viewer. У меня задача запустить сервер (AggreGate, это интеграционная платформа) в автозапуске. Сервер может загружаться только с правами суперпользователя. В /etc/rc.local я записываю строку /opt/AggreGate/ag_server. После перезагрузки сервер запускается, но на java iKVM Viewer пустота (NO SIGNAL). Я вырубаю сервер через удаленный клиент и система загружается полноценно. т.е. на java iKVM Viewer появляется рабочий стол. Я предполагаю, что это происходит т.к. загрузка происходит до полной загрузки системы и идет ожидание завершения загрузки сервера AG, но сервер не вырубается никогда. Т.е. он вдет логи, работает и т.д., нет момента завершения работы сервера, а значит система будет ждать завершения загрузки сервера вечно. Так ли я понимаю механизм автостарта /etc/rc.local? Как мне запустить при старте сервер от имени админа так, что бы и система загружалась полностью?

Comment: Написать нормальный systemd-сервис?

Comment: в бэкграунд, небось, не отправили ваш процесс.